# Installing SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I'm having a problem installing SQL Server 2008 on my windows 7 32 bit machine. I get an unhandled exception error message.

Any solutions for these?

Thanks.

Comment: two problems = two `seperate` questions please

Comment: What happen if you click on "Detail"?

Comment: If you down vote, you should offer some constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried searching the web for "sql server 2008 b77a5c561934e089"?

- [Sql Server 2008 R2 Express install problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/90df9616-c269-48b0-8951-f50e0c2fabca)
- [SQL Server 2008 Setup - Microsoft Corporation: Software](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/49a20ee4-7f21-41da-99f3-b031411c747e)
- [Microsoft Framework Error While Installing SQL SERVER 2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlgetstarted/thread/6eb11052-2508-4446-9c41-f7b4047de984)

Two of these posts suggest deleting the C:\Users\rethabile\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation folder and trying again.  The other says that you can't install on a drive that is compressed.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted the folder and started again, and the installation was a success.